# "In" or "On" the pan/plate/bowl

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Hey are the prepositions in the sentences below correct?

> The food **on** this plate looks amazing!
>
> Melt some butter **in** the pan and then put the eggs.
>
> Put the spaghetti **in** the bowl and then pour some tomato sauce over them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The *food* on this plate looks amazing.

Using dish in this sentence doesn't sound right. Though you are meaning to say dish as in a meal, dish also can mean like plate or bowl, so we usually never say dish on the plate.

> Melt some butter in the pan, then put *in* the eggs

You would put the eggs eggs *in* the pan, not just put the eggs.

> Put the spaghetti in the bowl and then pour some tomato sauce over *it*.

Your pronoun here is incorrect.

Comment: (Even though *spaghetti* is plural in Italian, in English it is a mass noun.)